# How many persons did create the world?

Tags: nature-of-god, genesis

In Genesis 1 it says **"Let us.."**
So how many persons have to be it at least? At least two or at least three?

Comment: Which translation of the Bible are you using?  Have you looked up in an on line concordance (Strong's is a standard one" what the original Greek rendering was?) Welcome to ChristianitySE.  [Tour], [ask] and [answer] guidance is good to review before asking a question, as is some basic research.

Comment: A Trinitarian would generally argue that the use of plural pronouns there suggests the Trinity AND that the three persons necessarily worked together in the act of creation

Answer (score 1):

The most common interpretation oft this is that God is referring to himself, the three-person [Trinity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trinity) making up one God.